# How to preserve Expand/Collapse Setting in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

This is how I collapse the desired sections of designer code (aspx).

[image: My Collapsed View]

But once I close and re-open the project then everything gets expanded in outline view like this.

[image: VS automatically expands all when the project is closed and reopened]

How to preserve my collapsed sections setting?

Answer (score 0):

Enclose these codes using `#region` and `#endregion`:

```
#region
<head> ...
...
#endregion
```

And tick the `Collapse #region when collapsing to definitions`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  But I would like to preserve the collapse feature in ASPX code window not in code behind.  Also, I don't see that option in my version of VS.

Comment: Unfortantly? visual studio will remember the collapse settings for code behind, but it NEVER did remember the same for the markup side of things. You colipase code, and hit save? Sure, - it remembers. But for markup side? Nope, Visual Studio does not remember those settings, and never did.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer.  It's very hectic to collapse sections every time when working with huge markup codes.